How to count a pattern inside a phrase?
For example:
/A/B/C/D/

I know that this command:
awk -FS'/' '{print $1}'

Prints the first pattern: A
But, how can I count the number of '/' inside that phrase? The output will be: 5

Try awk -F/ '{print NF-1}'.

or awk '{print gsub("/","")}' (will be more robust in reporting 0 instead of -1 for empty input lines).

You might inform GNU AWK that / is field using FPAT built-in variable and then check number of fields, let file.txt content be
/A/B/C/D/

then
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="/"}{print NF}' file.txt

gives output
5

(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
